# sqlalchemy , AmbiguousForeignKeysError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wrote two models, one is the "User", and the other is "User_address", has another foreign key point between them, then appeared the following questions

AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User_address.user - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone = Column(String, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)

    nickname = Column(String)


    default_address_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('user_address.id'))
    default_address = relationship('User_address')


class User_address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    user = relationship('User', backref='addresses')
    address = Column(String, nullable=False)
    lng = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    lat = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a [mutually-dependent](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_persistence.html#rows-that-point-to-themselves-mutually-dependent-rows) relationship because the `user_address.user_id` refers to `user`, but `user.default_address_id` refers to `user_address`.

Following the example in the documentation and adapting it to your use case produces something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, ForeignKey, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class User_address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    address = Column(String, nullable=False)
    lng = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    lat = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone = Column(String, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    nickname = Column(String)

    default_address_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('user_address.id'))
    addresses = relationship(User_address, backref='user',
                             primaryjoin=
                                id==User_address.user_id
                            )

    default_address = relationship(User_address,
                                   primaryjoin=
                                       default_address_id==User_address.id,
                                   post_update=True)
```

The trick to resolving the `AmbiguousForeignKeysError` is the [primaryjoin](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.primaryjoin) argument that tells the relationship mapper explicitly what SQL join conditions to use.

Comment: I was only able to get this to work when the `User` class was defined after `User_address`. My first pass had the `User` class defined before the `User_address` class with the `primaryjoin` parameters using strings like `"User_address.id"` (because the class was defined below). I had to move the `User` class below so that it could reference the real `User_address.id` variable & then everything worked