# AmbiguousForeignKeysError even after specifying foreign_keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm setting up some table objects for SQLAlchemy.
I have a user and checkout tables. I want to associate a user object with the checkin and the checkout, which are both recorded in the same checkout object, so I have an in_user and out_user associated with each checkout object.

I've run into a `sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError`

To quote the exact error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Checkout.out_auth_user - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

I've done as the error message requests (see below), but the error still occurs.

I originally only specified user email because I wanted to be able to remove users in the future without corrupting historical data. However, I tried to add user id, but still got the same error.

There are many similar questions on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find one that addressed my problem and most of them are working with much older versions of sqlalchemy that did not support the `foreign_keys` argument to relationship. It seems like this often occurs with backreferences, but I'm not using those as far as I'm aware. This is a simple one-way link from a checkout object to two user objects.

[Flask foreign_keys still shows AmbiguousForeignKeysError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044173/flask-foreign-keys-still-shows-ambiguousforeignkeyserror)

[sqlalchemy , AmbiguousForeignKeysError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965983/sqlalchemy-ambiguousforeignkeyserror)

The full code is on github at https://github.com/ACMWM/hwcheckout

Below is an MRE

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy import Column, Boolean, Integer, String, ForeignKey, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

db = "sqlite:///mre.db"
engine = create_engine(db, convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)

class HW(Base):
    __tablename__ = "HW"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Checkout(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Checkouts"

    what = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(HW.id))
    hardware = relationship(HW, foreign_keys=[what])

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    out_auth_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    out_auth_email = Column(String, ForeignKey(User.email))
    out_auth_user = relationship(User, foreign_keys=[out_auth_id, out_auth_email])

    in_auth_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    in_auth_email = Column(String, ForeignKey(User.email))
    in_auth_user = relationship(User, foreign_keys=[in_auth_id, in_auth_email])

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)

u = User(email="test@example.com")
chk = Checkout(out_auth_user_id=u.id,out_auth_user_email=u.email)
```

I'm using SQLAlchemy        1.3.3

EDIT: Remove double import of models. Same error still occurs

EDIT again: Got the MRE to reproduce the error

Postgres EDIT: Don't know if this helps, but when I tried to move my code to a real database, I got this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"
[SQL:
 CREATE TABLE "Checkouts" (
         id SERIAL NOT NULL,
         outdate TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
         returndate TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
         who VARCHAR,
         reason VARCHAR,
         quantity INTEGER,
         what INTEGER,
         out_auth_id INTEGER,
         out_auth_email VARCHAR,
         in_auth_id INTEGER,
         in_auth_email VARCHAR,
         PRIMARY KEY (id),
         UNIQUE (id),
         FOREIGN KEY(what) REFERENCES "HW" (id),
         FOREIGN KEY(out_auth_id) REFERENCES users (id),
         FOREIGN KEY(out_auth_email) REFERENCES users (email),
         FOREIGN KEY(in_auth_id) REFERENCES users (id),
         FOREIGN KEY(in_auth_email) REFERENCES users (email)
 )
]
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to get info which email had user when he/she checked in, and also get info which email had user when he/she checked out. I think that this is not possible with your model structure. Why don't you just create two tables and two models Checkin and Checkout, and you know exactly which email had user when a user checked in or checked out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your Checkout model definition:

```
class Checkout(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Checkouts"

    what = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(HW.id))
    hardware = relationship(HW, foreign_keys=[what])

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    out_auth_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    out_auth_email = Column(String, ForeignKey(User.email)) 

    in_auth_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    in_auth_email = Column(String, ForeignKey(User.email))

    out_auth_user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=[out_auth_id])
    in_auth_user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=[in_auth_id])

    out_auth_user_by_email = relationship('User', foreign_keys=[out_auth_email])
    in_auth_user_by_email = relationship('User', foreign_keys=[in_auth_email])
```

Documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths

Comment: So despite foreign_keys being a list, I should only use one column? odd. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the situation in your question, you should use one element list (as you can see in docs). But, you're right, it is pretty odd that there is a list,  I didn't have a situation where I used more than one element in the foreign_keys list.